# typescript error TS2531 Object is possibly 'null' is NOT being suppressed by strictNullChecks : false

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, ts-loader

My typescript compile is throwing the following error

> TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

I am converting code with an insane number of these errors and just want to suppress them to finish getting the build working. It was my understanding that adding the following in my tsconfig.json file would suppress this error.

> "compilerOptions": {
>           "strictNullChecks": false}

However the error still shows. I cannot find any other compilerOption specific to this error. Is there an option to suppress it?

Comment: you can use the non-null assertion operator ```!``` to coerce away those types, for e.g: ```let x = some.expr!.property```;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are not properly initializing some variables. You either can add a definite Assignment declaration with a ! or turn off the rule entirely. If this does not help some examples of failing code would be nice :)

To turn off add the folowing rule

> "strictPropertyInitialization": false

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
  }
}
```

Comment: You nailed it on both cases. This is the rule I was looking for! Also I went and looked at my property initializations and I had accidentally put this `private myVar: null;` I think I used my IDE to automatically add it and the IDE chose null for some reason, so fixed those and now have the option to disable the error. Thank you.